# in React app profiling child re-rendering with memo

Tags: reactjs, react-memo

In the profiling result the component (`Table`) uses `React.memo` and it is shown that did not re-render

[image: did not re-render]

but underneath there is shown the same `Table` component and in **Why did this render** is mentioned that parent re-rendered

[image: re-render]

The `Table` uses memo this way and the `querystring` stays the same.

```
function areEqal(prevTable, nextTable) {
  return prevTable.queryString === nextTable.queryString;
}
const MemoTable = memo(Table, areEqal);
...
<MemoTable queryString={queryString} />
```

The question is, why the `Table` is shown twice (once not re-rendered, then yes) and why it re-renders when memoized to re-render just when `querystring` changes.

Comment: Does Table use any context? (including custom hooks that use context)

Comment: @NicholasTower it did have this: const {userPreferences, setUserPreferences} = useContext(DataContext); but both were not used. Commenting it out - it does not re-render now. Great! Could you please comment on why the Table is twice in the profiler?

Comment: `Could you please comment on why the Table is twice in the profiler?` The first one is `MemoTable`, and it renders a `Table` component inside it. "Table (Memo)" is the default display name that memo gives the new component, but you can change it if you like: `const MemoTable = memo(Table, areEqal); MemoTable.displayName = "Hello world";`

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks! I guess those comments could be regular answer. I will accept it if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memo` can only prevent renders related to props. Rendering may still happen if a context value that you're subscribed to changes. As discussed in the comments, you are apparently using a couple of contexts, and those are what's causing the render.

While deleting the `useContext`s appears to have worked for your case, the fact that you weren't expecting this rerender may indidate that the DataContext.provider has a [common mistake](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) in which you're changing the context value on every render. If you're providing an object, you need to make sure to only create a new object when the properties of the object have actually changed. So for example, if your current code is this:

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
   const [userPreferences, setUserPreferences] = useState('something');

   return (
     <DataContext.Provider value={{ userPreferences, setUserPreferences }}>
       {children}
     </DataContext.Provider>
   );
}
```

... then you should memoize the value like this:

```
const Example = ({ children }) => {
   const [userPreferences, setUserPreferences] = useState('something');
   const value = useMemo(() => {
     return { userPreferences, setUserPreferences }
   }, [userPreferences]);

   return (
     <DataContext.Provider value={value}>
       {children}
     </DataContext.Provider>
   );
}
```

---

As for the two copies of `Table` in the dev tools, the first is the memoized component MemoTable. MemoTable then renders an unmemoized Table inside of it, and that's the second one. "Table (memo)" is the default name that `memo` gives to the component it returns. If you'd like to change that name so it shows up differently in the dev tools, you can:

```
const MemoTable = memo(Table, areEqal); 
MemoTable.displayName = "Hello world";
```